# JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize when using spring RestTemplate.exhange

Tags: json, spring, parsing, resttemplate

I am new to JSON and spring. Was able to write simple examples consuming REST webservices. But as I apply to realtime scenario, the JSON is nested, and I don't have control in changing the structure.

Below code giving me `Parse Error. Cannot deserialize instance of pg.domain.LookupDo[] out of START_OBJECT token`

```
LookupDo[] lookupDos =  template.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, LookupDo[].class).getBody();
```

How do I structure domain object?

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties
public class LookupDo {

    private String companyCode;
    private String plant;
    private String category;
    private String value;
    private String descr;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to match your class with your JSON structure

```
Response res = template.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, Response.class).getBody();
LookupDo[] lookupDos = res.getD().getResults();

public class Response{
   private Data d;
   ...
}
public class Data{
   private LookupDo[] results;
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But somehow, the data not loading, no more parse exception though, but CompanyCode, Plant etc, always coming null.
Just to check I've added __metadata (see my json object above), even-though its not needed, I added a class 'Metadata' and that part getting loaded. But not CompanyCode and Plant etc. I've spent enough time, making sure, nested objects are aligning with Json. Only thing, doubtful is variable case. The Json has upper case C in CompanyCode. In java I got companyCode. Not sure if its an issue. I tried either case but didn't work.

Comment: Make sure you are using getter setter and constructor for classes and `companyCode` -> `CompanyCode` capital the first one as in json

Comment: Sorry, still doesn't work. see by debug window screenshot https://i.imgur.com/9SZNMc9.jpg

Comment: Problem is upper camelcase in json I think, you can test with lower camelcase in json as your class.

Comment: Thanks. It worked finally. Appreciate. Yes. you are right. Finally, I spoke to the service provider (who prepares the json) asking him to give first char as lowercase and it worked finally. But somehow, I am not convinced the way we did it. (1) Having so many nested objects (2) enforcing to have json attribute first char lowercase. There must be a better/cleaner solution. Anyways, made it work. Thanks for your time Rono